# Why did Hitler's order to give SS members German Citizen remain in force until the 1960s?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, hitler

[Heinrich Boere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Boere) was allowed to find refuge in Germany while under death sentence from the Dutch. I guess the obvious answer to why Germany honored laws that applied to a criminal organization is that individuals "in good faith" served in the SS expecting German citizenship.

But why would Germany even want to keep a Hitler-issued law in effect at all let alone so long after WW2 ended? When I looked at the German language article about Fuhrerlass, it was a general treatment of such laws, not this specific one.

Comment: According to Wikipedia there were several issues with this case. One point was that the legal status was unc

Comment: What "law"? Why "1960s", only in the title? Questions should be self-contained and provide evidence of prior research.

Comment: Regarding "But why would Germany even want to keep a Hitler-issued law in effect at all let alone so long after ww2 ended?": There are quite a number of laws that have been put into effect during the Third Reich that are still in effect _today_. See for example [this list](https://www.bundestag.de/resource/blob/711220/68f6915e1c63bf882fd15bae5f755401/WD-3-160-20-pdf-data.pdf) compiled by the "Wissenschaftliche Dienste" of the "Deutscher Bundestag" (the "scientific services department" of the German parliament) from 2020. It lists 31 laws, most minor and technical, but still ;)

Comment: This is wholly unclear to me. You write _"general treatment"_… _"not this specififc one",_ yet accept an answer that exclusively deals with "this specific one"? That makes title incongruent to body, and then question incongruent to answer? If you want to know about "keep a Hitler-issued law in effect", then a rephrasing (away from the presumably arbitrary & thus misleading example?) might be in order?

Comment: @LangLangC I understood the sentance to mean that the [Führererlass – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BChrererlass) ([Adolf Hitler's directives - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler%27s_directives)) dealt with the topic generaly, but not specificly about the one the OP was interested in (effecting the nationality laws in the Heinrich Boere case).

Comment: @MarkJohnson Interesting twist to interpret, & I agree: that _might_ be possible from QOPs intent. But opens another question re:answer. It deals in oblique way with 'extradition of citizens' (prevented by basic law), but _not_ why 1. 43-decree wasn't nullified after 45 ("remained in force"; as many others))? 2. That the issue thus would become '_became_ citizen' would be nullified (not loss of it avoided; legally distinct, as he then 'could not loose what he never had', if that'd be included, it'd need 'explanation', bit more than "2nd sentence"). Since QOP won't edit Q, please add to your A.

Comment: @LаngLаngС I doubt that an official reason exists why it wasn't nullified. So an answer to that would only be speculative.

Comment: Please [edit] title to "citizenship"; and either remove "1960s" (_this case_ had the _'presumed'_ effect of the 1943 decree shown _in 1980! And later, up to 2008 and even 'now')_ — or: quote your source dealing with this issue in the 1960s!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But why would Germany even want to keep a Hitler-issued law in effect at all let alone so long after ww2 ended?

Because the Basic Law (Constitution) Article 16(1) does not generally allow citizenship to be revoked. This provision was introduced as a result of the wide spread misuse during the period between 1933–45.

Article 16(2), as it was until 2000 when the second sentance was added, did not permit the extradition of German citizens to other countries.

> [Article 16 [Citizenship - Extradition] - Basic Law for the Federal Republic of Germany](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_gg/englisch_gg.html#p0090)
> (1) No German may be deprived of his citizenship. Loss of citizenship may occur only pursuant to a law and, if it occurs against the will of the person affected, only if he does not become stateless as a result.
> (2) No German may be extradited to a foreign country.

Based on the [Decree of 1943-05-19](https://www.servat.unibe.ch/dns/RGBl_1943_I_315_EF_Erwerb_deutscher_Staatsangehoerigkeit_Einstellung_deutsche_Wehrmacht_Waffen-SS_deutsche_Polizei_Organistation_Todt.pdf) (PDF):

> (1) Deutschstämmige Ausländer, die der deutschen Wehrmacht, der Waffen-SS, der deutschen Polizei oder der Organisation Todt angehören, erwerben mit der Verkündung dieses Erlasses die deutsche Staatsangehörigkeit.
>
> > (1) Foreigners of German origin who belong to the German Wehrmacht, the Waffen-SS, the German police or the Organization Todt acquire German citizenship upon the promulgation of this decree.
>
> ...

[Heinrich Boere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Boere), who was born in Germany of a Dutch father and a German mother, was a German citizen when the Basic Law came into effect on the 25th of May 1949.

Your quoted article also states:

> According to Dutch law, being convicted of serving the army of the enemy automatically leads to the loss of Dutch citizenship.

so even if the the Decree of 1943-05-19 had been nullified after the 25th of May 1949, the second sentance of Article 16(1) would have prevented the loss of citizenship.

Comment: The specific case would also benefit from showing that a Cologne court received the specific Dutch extradition request _in 1980,_ (Q introduces "1960s" out of nowhere?) and then denied it because it only "_could be the case_ that B received his German citizenship through the 1943 decree". A then Dortmund based inquiry found that a convinction would be an unrealistic prospect, as his actions would be deemed legal… A view then changed by 2008.

Comment: @LаngLаngС One could also argue that since many countries, then and now, offer citizenship to foreigners who serve in their armed forces there was no need for it to be nullified. The fact that it was no longer in effect was sufficient.